# Can the famous multistage graph algorithm for shortest distance be solved in Order of no. of stages?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

For those who are not sure what multistage graph is:
https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-use-multistage-graph-problems-1

Please share your algorithm if you can solve it in order of no. of stages.

Comment: Sound like a question for Code Golf (http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), but not a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: You need at least `O(m)` to solve any shortest path problem where `m` is the number of edges in the Graph because you need to inspect each edge at least once. If you don't inspect some edges, how would you know that a shorter path doesn't exist via some of the uninspected edges? I am not sure what you mean by the "number of stages", but if that number is less than `m`, then the answer is clearly no.

Comment: @wookie919, so how do you solve any shortest path problem in order of m?

Comment: @UlsaMinor If the graph has unit edge costs (i.e. all edge cost is 1) then a simple breadth-first-search solves the shortest-path problem in `O(m)` time. That's as simple as it gets. What I am saying is, if `s` is the "number of stages" (still unclear what that means), and `s < m`, then it is VERY unlikely that you will be able to come up with an algorithm that has a time complexity only in terms of `s` e.g. `O(s)`.

Comment: yeah exactly, thank you!

Comment: @wookie919, however the bfs algorithm will solve it in order of no. of edges plus vertices, isn't it and not order of edges. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @UlsaMinor If `m < n`, some vertices will not be reachable. If you start BFS from from a single vertex, you would almost always end up inspecting more edges than vertices, special case being a tree with no parallel edges, where the number of edges inspected will be the same is the number of vertices inspected. In other words, you can assume `m >= n`, and thus `O(m)`